# What should be desired output for ANN

Tags: neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

The Back-Propagation Algorithm as described in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0308031.pdf) guide/introduction is confusing, the final formula generated for del(w)(change in weights) is
[image: del(w) formula]

del(w<sub>ji</sub>) - Change in weights of synapse from j to i;

eta (n) - learning factor;

O<sub>j</sub> - Output of previous layer j;

d<sub>j</sub> - Desired output from previous layer j;

x<sub>i</sub> - Input

---

I have few doubts associated with the formula.

What is the desired output for hidden layer and Input layer??

What is the j and i notation?

What should be the learning factor how can I decide(or generate) the value of learning factor i.e eta(n)?

<sup>**Note:** I want it to work like [this](https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/) (there would be differences in some factors but formulations should be similar..I cannot see any similarity in the formulations).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the desired output for hidden layer and input layer?

The hidden layers and input layers don't have a desired output.

Each neuron has an error, which for the output neurons is calculated as `target activation - current activation`.

Hidden neurons and output calculate their error as follows (psuedocode):

```
foreach(otherNeuron in myProjectedConnections):
  myError += otherNeuron.error * connection.weight
```

`myProjectedConnections` is a list containing all the neurons to which a certain neuron passes on its activation value.

#### What is the `i` and `j` notation?

Your question contains the answer: `del(wji) - Change in weights of synapse from j to i;`

A synapse is a fancy word for a connection. So `j` is a neuron and `i` is a neuron, with `j` projecting a connection to  `i`.

#### What should the learning factor be?

The learning factor should be a factor anywhere in the range of `0-1`. If you set your learning factor to 1, a network will learn the output to *one* test case immediately. If you want to teach it patterns however, choose a value anywhere in the range of `0-0.3`, depending on your situation ofcourse.

Comment: Do you know anything about Rprop(Resilient Back propagation), Rprop uses (changes) learning factor to calculate new delw. What if I use Rprop instead of BackProp, which is better?